# How to convert a Blazor WASM standalone app to a hosted one

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a large working Blazor WASM app. When I started I thought I wanted a free standing one. Now I realize I should have select hosted - ie have it served by a separate asp.net web server. In order to see how that client seever combo should work I have created a test app in that configuration and cannot work out how it works.

The Web server BlazorApp1.Server is serving files from the wwwroot of the BlazorApp1.Client. But I dont see how it is getting to those files. I looked at the EnvironMent.WebRoot of the server and its not set, its ContentRoot points to itself

Apart from the webroot issue are there any other changes I would need to make. I looked at the project templates and could not see any obvious ones

Comment: Use a git repo to identify the differences. Create one without commit then paste a hosted one with the same name space and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no differences in the Client project between Hosted and Standalone.

In the Hosted setup, in your Server the key points are:

- The Server project has a Project Reference to the Client
- The Program.cs should have `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();`
  and `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");`

I would create a new Hosted project and drop in the original Client project, fix the names (and namespaces) and link the Server to the right Client.

---

plus need to add nuget packages

- microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly
  //- microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.devserver
- microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.server

I also added `app.UseStaticFiles`

Actually no, dont add devserver to the Server app. You want Server in the server app and devserver in the client

DevServer is a minimal kestrel server hard coded to nice defaults just for booting up a blazor wasm client. It also supports the debugging of the client c# code.

Comment: i was really curious to find out how the server finds the clients wwwroot. I have traced it as far as it loads their names from BlazorApp4\Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\BlazorApp4.Server.staticwebassets.runtime.json , which is a copy of the client staticweb assets file, but I am still trying to see how that file (in the server project) gets built. It gets made by the server project, but the only pointer to the client I see is in the project dependecy. Maybe that triggers it

Comment: Yes, the relevant output from Client is copied to Server\bin. It was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62345887/60761)

Comment: I am going to edit in my additional changes